# Should we apply for Tourist eVisa if we already have Business eVisa

Tags: visas, india, tourist-visas, e-visas

Me and my husband (Both Indonesian citizen) would like to visit India in March for Holiday.
I don't have visa yet so I will be applying Tourist eVisa, but my husband already have a Business eVisa (multiple entry in 1 year - issued 3 months ago). Should my husband apply for a Tourist eVisa (So he will have 2 visa), or it should be good to use the Business eVisa for holiday?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In *theory*, the Business eVisa is for business purposes only, not tourism.  However, the allowed business purposes are so broadly worded that virtually anything qualifies: if you buy a souvenir, you could argue that this is "trade" or "sales/purchases".

```
For technical and business meetings.
To set up Industrial or business venture.
To deliver lectures under Global Initiative for Academic Networks (GIAN).
For recruitment purposes.
For trade or sales / purchases.
To participate in exhibitions, business or trade fairs.
```

(From [here](https://indiaevisas.org/india-business-visa/); this is *not* an official site, but the [official one](https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/evisa/tvoa.html) is an unlinkable mess)

In *practice*, Indian immigration seems almost entirely concerned with whether you have a visa or not, I've never been questioned on arrival.  So, *personally* speaking, I think you'll be fine with the business visa.